# Fate of Miss Justineau in "the Girl with All the Gifts"

Tags: plot-explanation, girl-with-all-the-gifts

At the end of [the Girl with All the Gifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_with_All_the_Gifts_(film)) Miss Justineau is crying before she gets up to teach the children.

Why is that? I can understand that being permanently alone and stuck in that tin can would be an unpleasant future, but is that the reason? (I didn't read the book.)